# how to get file name from the server request?

Tags: java, httprequest, server

I'm trying http requests and create http get request to server. Server must return .zip file. here is the code:

```
        url = new URL(urlToRead);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        is = conn.getInputStream();
```

then I want to write it to file like this:

```
    r = 1;
    while(r > 0){
     r = is.read(buf);
     if(r > 0)
    fos.write(buf, 0, r);
   }
```

but to create fileoutputstream i want to use the file name provided by server. I've found that server answer has the file name and all the structure looks like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 07 Apr 2003 14:51:19 GMT
Server: Apache/1.3.20 (Win32) PHP/4.3.0
Last-Modified: Mon, 07 Apr 2003 14:51:00 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 673
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=test.zip
Pragma: no-cache

....(zip content)
```

how to get filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `HttpUrlConnection` object's `getHeaderField()` method to read the Content-Disposition header. Also make sure you handle the case when it is not present.

Comment: yes, I've found this. but is there any good looking way to get filename than  String contentDisposition = conn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            int fileNamePosition = contentDisposition.lastIndexOf("fileName");
            String filename = contentDisposition.substring(fileNamePosition+9);?

Comment: @NikitinMikhail It is the only way to do it, and it won't be bad looking really.

Comment: String filename=conn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition").split("filename=")[1].trim();

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at the methods that [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) offers?

Especially the ones that involve `headers`?

Answer (score 0):

if u have servletRequest object(lets say obj) then 
i think this will help

```
obj.getRequestURL() ;
```